# Loading PHAsset data FAST.

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, assets

I am using `requestimageforasset` to load assets, just as described in the Apple Dev Documentation.

It works and all, but I find it very very VERY slow when it comes to very large assets, such as videos of several hundreds of megabytes.

My goal is to load an asset, copy a chunk of its data, and send that chunk to a server.

I load chunks because of obvious reasons, RAM limitation.

I have a couple of questions in mind about this:

1. How can I copy chunks of large video assets really fast?
2. Can I get any direct and fast access to asset data without calling
   `requestimageforasset`?
3. Should I maintain the `requestimageforasset` open until I send the
   data and then leave it's completion block?

So, what approach should I take and where can I find info about this?

Comment: Well, `requestimageforasset` returns an NSData containing the video data right? So I copy a chunk of 2 million bytes (2MB) and send it to the server using NSOutputStream via TCP. 
Could you elaborate on what you mean with "why don't you just do the upload?" and also what difference it would make if giving it to a background session?

Comment: My point here is about RAM and CPU efficiency really. I don't want to keep the asset data loaded in memory for no reason. I rather take a chunk of it, and then close it, followed by sending the chunk and repeating the process when I need another chunk.

Comment: Btw, I'm talking of NSData, like, raw data. Not "chunks" as in a bunch of frames but rather raw binary data.

Comment: And finally: I send chunks of the video data to the server, the server then stitches everything together. The reason being that if a chunk is defected during transmission, then the server can just ask for that chunk again rather than re-sending the whole file.

Comment: But that's what I'm saying. Don't put it in memory at all. Use PHAssetResourceManager to access the data directly and start the upload task and walk away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91222/discussion-between-vaid-and-matt).