# Creating a thread that waits for input.

Tags: ios, multithreading, wait

I asked a question earlier today ([find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918479/loading-phasset-data-fast-xcode-ios?noredirect=1#comment53664703_32918479)) regarding sending
large data to a server, and a person commented and said that a background task
should handle the job.

I am assuming that he/she means that a thread should handle the task.

**So my question now is**: How do I create a thread that waits for input?

The process will look something like this:

1. Main thread (MT) tells the worker thread (WT) to load an asset
2. WT copies a chunk of data from the asset and assembles a network packet
3. WT sends the network packet and waits
4. WT waits for MT to tell it when to repeat step 2 through 4

When data has been fully transmitted the thread is destroyed.

**Note**: I am not using HTTP, I am using TCP with my custom protocol on top of TCP.

**Explanation:**
The reason I need to keep the thread waiting is because when I open a very large asset of 200MB or larger, it takes some time for the asset to be loaded.

The larger the asset data, the longer time the app has to wait.

If I want just a 2MB chunk of the asset, I have to load the asset, wait some time for it to be loaded, copy a chunk of 2MB, and then exit the completion block.

Then I send the data, and wait for the server to send an ACK signal, and repeat the process.

This will take some time and the network activity shows that there are several seconds of dead-time where the app isn't doing anything, and that's all because of time it takes for the asset to be loaded.

The person in my previous question said that it's better to load the asset in a background task and NOT LEAVE the completion block of `requestImageForAsset` and simply keep the task running until the chunk has been sent, and then send the next chunk.

I hope this clears any further confusions.

Comment: Not sure about your wait and chunking logic but I'd suggest that `NSOperationQueue` is a useful abstraction over threads if you don't need very low-level control.

Comment: @PhillipMills I could explain exactly what I am doing if you'd like to. I don't really need anything low-level. I just need a task that runs along the main thread and stays active until the main thread tells it to do something.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is, you don't.

Every time the main thread notices that an asset needs to be loaded, it should put a job on a dispatch queue to load the asset.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/

You don't mention if you are using Swift or Objective-C. Either way, this should make sense:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ 
    // copy a chunk of data from the asset and assemble a network packet
    // send the network packet and wait
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // inform the main thread that the information has been received.
    });
});
```

Also check out this resource: http://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1

Comment: But I have to. I've updated the question where I explain why I need to keep the thread waiting.

Comment: I've read your update and no, you don't need to manually keep the thread alive. The OS will take care of that minutiae for you.

Comment: I've read your new update. My answer is still the correct answer. The code I present puts a task on a background thread and lets it run without interfering with the main thread's UI jobs for as long as it needs to. This answer has nothing to do with network calls and everything to do with how you create and manage threads in iOS.

Comment: Oh ok. But if I ask you this: how long will the thread be alive?

Comment: Will it terminate as soon as the code in it has been executed?
I need to somehow keep it alive and wait for a command.

Comment: It doesn't matter. That isn't something you need to worry about. Just put the job on a queue and the the OS worry about which threads do what. Note, there are several queues with different priorities and specific rules about which jobs should go on which queues. Read Apple's documentation to make sure you are using the correct queue.

Comment: I have read the documentation. I can't find anything about giving a thread alive and wait for input. That's what I am asking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91248/discussion-between-daniel-t-and-vaid).